# How can i create a server-side authentication system with express.js and firebase?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, express, authentication

I have already tried it with the code below however once i login every device on my network is capable of automatically logging in. How can I create a secure authentication system?

```
.post('/logIn', async (req, res) => {
    const context = { error: false }
    await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, req.body.email, req.body.password)
        .catch(err => {context.error = true})
    if (context.error) {
        return res.render('auth/logIn.ejs', context)
    } else {
        return res.redirect('/')
    }
})
```

If possible can somebody redirect me to a youtube video or article from which I can find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can dictace the behavioir using **auth state persistence**

```
import { getAuth, setPersistence, signInWithEmailAndPassword, browserSessionPersistence } from "firebase/auth";

const auth = getAuth();
setPersistence(auth, browserSessionPersistence)
  .then(() => {
   
    return signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // Handle Errors here.
    const errorCode = error.code;
    const errorMessage = error.message;
  });
```

This will log out users if they end their session, i.e, close their browser.

You can read more about it here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence